# Search returns incorrect document title

Tags: search, document

Search returns incorrect document title in SharePoint 2013 Search results page.Please suggest.How can we correct document title in search.

Comment: Can you include screenshot of list item properties as well as screenshot with search results?

Comment: Check the metadata (title) from the document.

Answer (score 0):

Check the metadata that is held within the documents that are being returned in the search results.  If these are Office files, such as a word document, you can see the metadata properties by opening it up in MS Word and looking for **Info** under the **File** ribbon tab.

If there is a Title present in the document metadata properties, SharePoint may give this precedence over the metadata in SharePoint, particularly if there is no Title metadata in SharePoint for the given result.

Answer (score -2):

Check the Mapping of Managed metadata and Crawled properties.

Comment: Which metadata property ?